# Orthogonal basis with respect to $\phi$ must contain $ker \phi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Does a basis which is orthogonal with respect to a bilinear symmetric form $\phi$ necessarily contain the vectors of $ker \phi$ ?

Since the vectors in $ker \phi$ are orthogonal to all the vectors in the vector space $V$ where $\phi$ is defined, must they be present in all the orthogonal bases with respect to $\phi$?

Thanks for your help

**Edit** : with "vectors of $\ker \phi$" I mean the vectors of a basis of $ker \phi$

**2nd Edit** : $V$ is finite dimensional and $\phi : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined for the reals

Comment: $0$ is always in $\ker \phi$ yet cannot belong to any basis.

Comment: Well, yes, a basis of $\ker\phi$ can be a base for building a $\phi$-orthogonal basis. I'm not sure if any $\phi$-orthogonal basis must contain a basis for $\ker\phi$. I guess that's what you wanted to ask.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant!

Comment: In the finite dimensional case this result follows from the singular value decomposition. In infinite dimensions for general bilinear forms (unbounded, not closed, etc), I don't know, and it seems like a pretty hard question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I forgot to mention that $V$ is finite dimensional and that $\phi$ is defined for the reals. Is this valid in the real case?